# Installing a program on C:\Program Files\Program instead of C:\Program Files\Manufacturer\Program Name

Tags: .net, setup-kit

i think the question says it all, but I have an application that uses a .net setup kit (in vs.2005), and the user asked me if it was possible to install it on the c:\Program Files\ProgramName instead of C:\Program files\Manufacturer\Program Name. Thing is, I just can't seem to find the way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Considering this 1. breaks installation conventions, and 2. is of limited utility considering almost no one goes hunting in the program files direction, I'd lean towards steering the client in a different direction.

Comment: I can argue all I want but I can't win them all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long time so I might be mixing up the versions, but I think it's something like:

1. Open the `FileSystem` page.
2. Right click on the `Application` folder and select properties.
3. Change the `DefaultLocation` to something like `[ProgramFiles]\[ProductName]`.

Comment: Thanks. It's easy once you know it, but not exactly easy to find :)